# Yii, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined CheckBoxList

Tags: php, yii

I initially have a dropDownList of `Service`:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'service_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'service_id', GxHtml::listDataEx(Service::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true))); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'service_id'); ?>
</div><!-- row -->
```

I then want to turn it into a checkBoxList:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'service_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'service_id', CHtml::listData(Service::model()->findAll(),'id','serviceInfo'),
            array( 
                'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
            )
    );?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'service_id'); ?>
</div><!-- row -->
```

Unfortunately, it now gives me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Can I know what I have done wrong? Please do guide me. Thanks

Comment: What does CHtml::listData($model->service(array('condition'=>'active=1')),'id','serviceInfo') return?

Comment: an array of services.

Comment: Can you show it? Or even try to replace that with an array filled with static content, just to see if that is the problem.

Comment: plz show the `var_dump($model->service(array('condition'=>'active=1')));` result

Comment: Oh! It's NULL I'm guessing there's something wrong in the $model->service area

Comment: Please see my updated code, I've changed that part to `Service::model()->findAll()`, did a var_dump, now everything's showing BUT still remains as a dropDownList with an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I was having a widget attached to it earlier, therefore after removing, it is working now. Thanks for all the helps.